# Remove justification from a longtable?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, longtable

Using :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[lmargin=3.81cm,tmargin=2.54cm,rmargin=2.54cm,bmargin=2.52cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.15\textwidth}|p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.35\textwidth}|p{0.2\textwidth}|}
  .
  .
  .
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

How do I remove justification from the table ? What about only the 4th column ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add

```
\usepackage{array}
```

and replace

```
p{0.15\textwidth}
```

by

```
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.15\textwidth}
```

in any columns where you want ragged text.

Comment: This is identical to the Related" question in the right so this question should be closed as duplicate

Comment: Better still, load the `ragged2e` package and issue the directive `>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}`. Doing so (re)enables hyphenation of words contained in the column in question.