# Why doesn't raggedright work in the last column of a tabular (with package array)?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}l>{\em}l}
A & B \\
E & F
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}l>{\raggedright}l}
A & B \\
E & F
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I want to make all the columns of the table `\raggedright` (in the real example then the columns are of `X` variant and I'm using `tabularx`, but the error shows up in the above).  Using the `\array` package I appear to be able to successfully insert `\raggedright` in each column except the last.

What's going wrong here?

(If there's a better way of making all columns of a table `\raggedright` then I'd be happy to know that as well.)

Comment: Look for `\arraybackslash` in the documentation of `array` and on the site

Comment: as egreg said, or use `\tabularnewline` instead of `\\ ` to end the table row.

Comment: this question, although marked as a duplicate, has relevant information: [Remove justification from a longtable?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/109023/579)